nvcc error : 'cudafe++' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)
I tried to run a cuda file in "Developer Powever for VS 2022" by following command:
PS C:\Temp> nvcc hello.cu
hello.cu
nvcc error   : 'cudafe++' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)

It can not compile, and then I check the location of my "cl.exe" file
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools> where.exe cl
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe

Then I reset the path of cl.exe file by:
PS C:\Temp> $env:PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64;" + $env:PATH
PS C:\Temp> where.exe cl
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe


It then compile successfully
PS C:\Temp> nvcc hello.cu
hello.cu
tmpxft_00008020_00000000-10_hello.cudafe1.cpp
  Creating library a.lib and object a.exp

The problem here seems the default path to cl.exe is "...\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe", however the correct path for it should be "...\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe". Since "$env:PATH" can only modify the enviroment variable temporaly. I want to how to modify it permanently in Powershell. I've tried to modify it in Windows GUI, but fails.

This question is similar to: Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You saved me, I am very grateful. This problem has been bothering me for over a month, and I have tried various solutions over the past month, but all have ended in failure. In the end, I found an issue in your post, so my device does not support cl.exe for x86 programs to compile CUDA source files, and must use cl.exe with x64 architecture. Based on this idea, I modified the environment variables, removed their x86 path, and added the path of the x64 program, which solved the problem.

Many thanks for your help, I've tried to modify the environment variables directly, but this can not solve my problem. Seems like you cannot modify the path in Developer Powever for VS 2022 by modifying the environment variables directly

I solved this build error and can set environment clearly.
Note:
the  "Developer PowerShell for VS *" is set x86 build tools, see capture picture right:
See build tools is x86
You should run command in the same powershell window to switch to x64 build tools:
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1" -Arch amd64 -HostArch amd64

Then, the build tools is x64 already! see capture picture right:
See build tools is x64
You may say WHY?
I found the Microsoft Developer Document with below documents:

Command-line arguments

Examples


You can have a try :)
